# L-infinity Approximation of Riemannian Manifolds with Bounded Ricci Curvature: Request for Review

Tags: dg.differential-geometry

An attempt to solve question number 2 from here [https://www.imo.universite-paris-saclay.fr/~pierre.pansu/problems_MTDG.pdf](https://www.imo.universite-paris-saclay.fr/%7Epierre.pansu/problems_MTDG.pdf) posed by Pierre pansu [https://www.imo.universite-paris-saclay.fr/~pierre.pansu/](https://www.imo.universite-paris-saclay.fr/%7Epierre.pansu/)

Hello, MathOverflow community,

I have been working on the L-infinity approximation of complete Riemannian manifolds with Ricci curvature bounded below. I would like to request a review of my attempt to construct a metric with two-sided Ricci curvature bounds that approximates the given manifold. Here is the outline of my approach:

1. Given a complete Riemannian manifold $(M, g)$ with injectivity radius $\operatorname{inj}(M, g) \geq \ell$ and Ricci curvature $\operatorname{Ric}(g) \geq k$, I first smooth the metric $g$ using a compactly supported smooth function $\varphi: M \to [0, \infty)$ and a small constant $\varepsilon > 0$. I define a new metric $g_\varepsilon$ on $M$ by $g_\varepsilon = g + \varepsilon \varphi g$.
2. Next, I approximate the smoothed metric $g_\varepsilon$ by a metric $h$ with two-sided Ricci curvature bounds. I define a new metric $h$ on $M$ by $h = g_\varepsilon + C_1 \chi g_\varepsilon$, where $\chi: M \to [0, \infty)$ is a smooth function chosen to control the Ricci curvature of $h$.
3. I show that for appropriately chosen $\chi$, the metric $h$ satisfies $|\operatorname{Ric}(h)| \leq K$ for some constant $K > 0$. This yields a metric $h$ that approximates the original manifold with the desired properties.

You can find the full LaTeX document containing the details of my approach here https://drive.google.com/file/d/1YHNYHyy9IHuZZ46Y_Gvv7cm84IrSwflg/view?usp=sharing. I would appreciate it if you could review my attempt and provide any feedback, corrections, or suggestions for improvement. In particular, I would like to know if there are any issues with the proof or if there are any more efficient methods for achieving the L-infinity approximation.

Thank you in advance for your valuable input!

Comment: Voted to close because MO is not the place to check correctness of your work, see https://mathoverflow.net/help/on-topic. Ask a specific question.

Comment: What is a good place?

Comment: I am not aware of a site that checks correctness of math research. The responsibility normally lies with the researcher. If I may make a suggestion, the right approach would be to think a bit more, isolate the step in your argument you are confused about, and then think of how to ask an intelligent question about the step. The latter would be welcome at MO.